# Macintosh Application location in case of dual monitor

Tags: macos, monitors

Suppose my Macintosh machine has dual monitors how can I accurately determine the monitor in which my application is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NSScreen mainScreen] returns the screen with the focused window. Call this method while you're application is activated

Answer (score 1):

Call [-[NSWindow screen]](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/screen) on the window you're interested in, e.g. your main window (keep in mind that if you have several windows each of them may be on a different screen).